# Testing if a string starts and ends with a certain string with RegExp in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am testing this string `"error code: 32603 error message: message here"` with this regex:
`RegExp(/^32603*/).test(string)` returns false every time

I want it to match only that exact string. Meaning I don't want it to return true just because it has a 3 in the string.

Comment: Start here https://regex101.com/

Comment: Well, your string doesn't start with `32603` it starts with `error code`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to know that the string contains the number `32603` you can use:

```
RegExp(/\s32603\s/).test(string)
```

It will match any string that contains this exact number with spaces around it.

If you want to handle the case that the number appears at the start or at the end of the string, use:

```
RegExp(/\b32603\b/).test(string)
```

Comment: There's no need for the *RegExp* constructor, there is a literal already so `/\s32603\s/.test(string)` will do. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

TRY IT:

```
<script>
            try {

                var util = {
                    startWith: function (source, search, ignoreCase) {
                        search = this.regExpEscapeSpecialCharacters(search);
                        var ignore = (ignoreCase) ? "gi" : "g";
                        var reg = new RegExp("^" + search + "", ignore);
                        return reg.test(source);
                    },
                    endWith: function (source, search, ignoreCase) {
                        search = this.regExpEscapeSpecialCharacters(search);
                        var ignore = (ignoreCase) ? "gi" : "g";
                        var reg = new RegExp(search + "$", ignore);
                        return reg.test(source);
                    },
                    contain: function (source, search, ignoreCase) {
                        search = this.regExpEscapeSpecialCharacters(search);
                        var ignore = (ignoreCase) ? "gi" : "g";
                        var reg = new RegExp(search, ignore);
                        return reg.test(source);
                    },
                    regExpEscapeSpecialCharacters: function (a) {
                        return  a.toString().replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
                    },
                };

                //EXAMPLES:
                var text = "hello world";
                var search1 = "he";
                var search2 = "ld";

                if (util.startWith(text, search1, true) && util.endWith(text, search2, true)) {
                    alert("match");
                }


            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);

            }

        </script>
```